# Can SQL Transaction lock rows only from specified view

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions, locking

In a multi-tenant application I have a table with TenantId column. This table is only accessed using a view which selects rows belonging to a single tenant using TenantId stored in `CONTEXT_INFO`. Is there a way to have transactions only locking data that this view returns for particular Tenant (ie. lock only rows with the same TenantId)?

It will be a performance loss if I lock the entire table when I'm sure the data being inserted/updated/deleted is never going to collide with those that have a different value in the TenantId column.

That same pattern would apply for any other View which limits some table rows using `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Is there a reason you have a shared table for all tenants instead of one for each?  If they are using views anyways, what's the reason for having a single shared table?

Comment: Sorry, to explain more: 
Any locks will persist for the duration of the view only unless in a transaction. But selecting won't normally be in a transaction...

Comment: Well the rows will get locked during all queries. You can read about locks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175519.aspx and an older but deeper explanation here: http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Adm/SQL70Locks.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a multi-tenant deployment the `TenantId` column **must** be the leftmost column in **every single index**, including the clustered index. Corollary is that you cannot have a a heap in multi-tenant applications.

If you follow this simple rule then, given that every single query **must** add the `TenantId=@currentTenantId` predicate, no query will ever 'wonder' outside the tenant data slice in any table. This will ensure that there is never contention between two tenants, since each one is interested in only his portion of the index.

A somehow similar solution can be achieved by using partitioning by `TenantId`, but given the current 1000 partitions limit and performance degradation inherent in partitioned tables, I would much stronger favor the index key solution.

There are thing that breaks this 'status-quo' like lock escalation (which can be explicitly disabled with [`ALTER TABLE SET LOCK_ESCALATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)) or bulk load table lock (disabled with with [`sp_tabeloption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173530.aspx)).

So, with this knowledge, can we revisit your question and reformulate it as 'Can we enforce isolation that a tenant can never lock resources owned by a different tenant?'. The answer is yes, as long as you ensure that there are proper tenant specific access paths in **every** rowset. Which translates to exactly what I say in my first paragraph: add the `TenantId` as the leftmost key to **every** index, including all clustered ones, and don't have any heaps. Small print would follow that solution will work most times, but there will always be specific scenarios in which a tenant can lock resources owned by a different tenant. But to isolate better you'd have to have one db per tenant, which is a nightmare for deployment/maintenance/upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for deep insight. I have one problem. The TenantId is never part of my clustered index since it wasn't neccessary. The Primary Key is mostly made of a single column so for Products it would be ProductId BIGINT IDENTITY. Is it good practice to still include the TenantId in the primary key although the ProductId identifies the row? My domain model is build on views (like here: http://blogs.imeta.co.uk/jyoung/archive/2010/03/22/845.aspx) and for the views the PK would be a single column since the view used by application isn't aware of the TenantId column. Will your solution still work?

Comment: And another thing - just to be sure: This rule obviously does not apply to tables containing common system data. They do not have a TenantId column at all. Is that correct?

Comment: clustered key and primary key are two different things. You may have your PK be `ProductId`, that's fine, but your clustering key should be `(TenantId, ProductId)`. The `@currentTenantId` should always be specified. Passing it through `CONTEXT_INFO` will work for most scenarios, but you need more than just WHERE clauses. All your JOINs must be on `a.TenantID=b.TenantID AND a.ItemId=b.PArentId`. And all your foreign keys must be declared as `FOREIGN KEY (TenantId, ParentId) REFERENCES Parent (TenantId, ItemId)`. Adding multi-tenancy will permeate every level of your design.

Comment: And yes,if you have system data that is shared by all tenants, then this rule does not apply. Note though that this shared data will always be a contention point between tenants: a tenant that locks exclusively any shared item, will block all other tenants. Given that usually the system data is never updated by tenants, that should not be a problem though, but keep it in mind.

Comment: This is great! Thanks for sharing. I'll try to do that and still be able to have multi-tenant ignorant model. Physically in my DB I will do exactly as you say. With Indexes and foreign keys. In my joins, though, I will try not do as you say since when a I join on two views the final condition will be `select * from a inner join b on a.ItemId = b.ParentId where a.TenantId = @tenantId and b.TenantId = @tenantId`. The were comes from two views. Wouldn't that be sufficient? Using WHERE and selecting from two tables ultimately is the same as JOIN isn't it? (At least my professor used to say that)

Comment: I hope the join by view will work fine. Your professor was right, but you have a different case here :). You have join between two views that each puts a predicate on its own TenantId column, not a predicate that matches the two TenantId columns. Also, you have a function involved: `WHERE TenantId = dbo.GetCurrentTenant()`. The optimizer cannot know that the filter in view A will return the *same* tenant as the filter in view B and it *may* create a very bad plan. Overall though, I would expect things to behave nicely and is an acceptable solution IMHO.

Comment: I can't vote up enough. I will most certainly verify the execution plans of such queries and compare them to those which directly match the two TenantId columns from both tables. I hope involving the function and indirect comparison won't be a BIG performance hit since I don't want my model to know anything about the TenantId and I don't want to pass the TenantId along with each query. This is prone to programming errors.

Comment: There are reasonably safe client side alternatives too. A Repository that exposes IQueryable<Products> and it returns for it `from p in products where p.TenantId = currentTenantId return p` works fine, because all access to the Repository.Products automatically adds the filter predicate. On my own project at bugcollect.com I use XML and XSLT to generate the data access layer (which is PHP) and the XSLT generators automatically add the appropriate predicate. So proper abstraction layer that handles the tenancy (the repository case) or code generation (my XML/XSLT case) are viable approaches.

Comment: But I would not go ahead and change your existing solution. I think that what you have, based on content and views, will work fine.

Comment: One thing is wrong in what you wrote unfortunately. "You may have your PK be ProductId, that's fine, but your clustering key should be (TenantId, ProductId)" then you write that "nd all your foreign keys must be declared as FOREIGN KEY (TenantId, ParentId) REFERENCES Parent (TenantId, ItemId)". Both statements conflict because a foreign key can't reference non-primary key. Then it's probably better to include TenantId in PK but still create a unique index on the former PK column (like ProductId in my example).

Comment: Still what you said about clustering the tables by `TenantId, OtherPKColumns` makes a lot of sense. Since the data will always be filtered by `TenantId` it's much better to keep one tenant's data together (also physically) than to fetch them from many different pages as would be with clustered index based only on the specific columns like `ProductId`.